# Why is that if the desire number not found in array it returns -1?

Tags: search, return, binary-search

i always thought of searching numbers and strings in a array or string and if i didn't found the number i wanted that it always give me -1 in return i think we all knows that but why is that , is the -1 bo any other number. i've been thinking this from a long time is there any specific reason when the search result is not found it reurns -1. any thoughts?

Logical explaination and it should be global and independent from any programming language.

Comment: Search algorithms return index of desired element. By returning `-1` search algorithm tells you that "there is no such index that points to desired element". Since arrays usually start from 0 then any negative number represents invalid index, but -1 is most convenient as it's most close to 0